# React component doesn't render even when the path changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

## App.jsx

```
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
import React from "react";
import Projects from "./Projects";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import {Routes,BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";


const App = () => {
    return(
        <>
            <style>{'body { background-color: black; }'}</style>
                <Navbar/>
                
                <Router>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
                        <Route exact path="/contact/" element = {<Contact/>}/>
                        <Route exact path="/projects/" element = { <Projects/>}/>
                    </Routes>
                </Router>
        </>
    );

};
export default App;
```

## Navbar.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import {NavLink,BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
const Navbar = ()=>{
   return(
<>
<Router>
    <div className="container-fluid nav_bg">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-10 ms-auto ">

      <nav className="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg transparent" id="nav1">
      <NavLink  className="brand-name " style={{color:"white"}} strict to="/">Shriharsh's Colosseum</NavLink>
      <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto brand-desc text-uppercase">
          <li className="nav-item active">
            <NavLink  className="nav-link"  style={{color:"white"}} strict to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink  className="nav-link"  style={{color:"white"}}  strict to="/projects/">Projects</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink  className="nav-link"  style={{color:"white"}} strict to="/contact/">Contact</NavLink>
   </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</Router>
   </>
   );
};

export default Navbar;
```

## The problem associated and what the code is intended to do:

I have a app with a navbar rendered nicely,now,for it's utility,even when the links are clicked the page doesn't seem to render it,even when the link changes.I tried searching for the solution for the similar problem and came across many but all of them seem to have their own unique cases of causation.I tried to changed path from `/path` to `/path/` to see if it would work by any change,it doesn't.Likewise,gave it a shot by changing the `NavLink` to `Link`,doesn't work.

Comment: The BrowserRouter component should wrap your whole application and to declare each route you should use the Routes component, assuming you are using react-router-dom v6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering the `Navbar` component and links into one router and the routes you want to link to in another router. You need only one router to provide a routing context to an entire React app.

## Solution

Remove the extraneous router the `Navbar` is rendering and move `Navbar` into the router that the `App` component is rendering.

Navbar.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    // <-- Router removed
    <div className="container-fluid nav_bg">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-10 ms-auto ">
          <nav className="...." id="nav1">
            <NavLink
              className="brand-name"
              style={{ color: "white" }}
              to="/"
            >
              Shriharsh's Colosseum
            </NavLink>
            <button ....>
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul className="....">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                  <NavLink className="nav-link" style={{ color: "white" }} to="/">
                    Home
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <NavLink
                    className="nav-link"
                    style={{ color: "white" }}
                    to="/projects"
                  >
                    Projects
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <NavLink
                    className="nav-link"
                    style={{ color: "white" }}
                    to="/contact"
                  >
                    Contact
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
import Projects from "./Projects";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Home from "./Home";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const App = () => {
  return(
    <>
      <style>{'body { background-color: black; }'}</style>
      <Router>
        <Navbar /> // <-- inside router
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={ <Projects />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

*Please also note that I removed the trailing `"/"` character on the routes.*

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [React Router dom v6 documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.6.0) the BrowserRouter wraps your app to store the current location of your app in the address bar, so your `index.jsx` should be like this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>{/* The rest of your app goes here */}</BrowserRouter>,
  root
);
```

then, to properly setup routes you should write in your App.jsx file your routes using the `Routes` and `Route` components.

Here's how your `App.jsx` should look like:

```js
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
import React from "react";
import Projects from "./Projects";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <style>{"body { background-color: black; }"}</style>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route exact path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Then, to navigate through the routes you declared in the `App.jsx` file you can use the `Link` component ([here's the documentation for it](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.6.0/components/link))

So, your `NavBar.jsx` should look like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid nav_bg">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-10 ms-auto ">
            <nav
              className="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg transparent"
              id="nav1"
            >
              <Link to="/" className="brand-name" style={{ color: "white" }}>
                Shriharsh's Colosseum
              </Link>
              <button
                className="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              >
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

              <div
                className="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="navbarSupportedContent"
              >
                <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto brand-desc text-uppercase">
                  <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link
                      to="/"
                      className="nav-link"
                      style={{ color: "white" }}
                    >
                      Home
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link
                      to="/projects"
                      className="nav-link"
                      style={{ color: "white" }}
                    >
                      Projects
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link
                      to="/contact"
                      className="nav-link"
                      style={{ color: "white" }}
                    >
                      Contact
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Do note that I removed the `Router` component from the Navbar since not necessary.